# Insert row to csv file after the last row

Tags: c#, csv, streamwriter

I have a function (is called: `writeToCsv`) that inserts rows to csv file.

I run the function row by row.

The problem is: my function inserts the row in the beginning of the file (that's why the previous row is deleted so I never get more than one row).

I want to know how to insert the row after the last row.

Any help appreciated!

```
var filePath = @"C:\Book1.csv";
// Initialise stream object with file
using (var wr = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    // Collection of book titles
    var row = new List<string>();


    // insert Username to Excel
    if (userdetails.username != "")
    {
        row.Add("Username: " + userdetails.username);
    }
    else
    {
        row.Add("Username: Unknown");
    }

    row.Add("");

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string value in row)
    {
        // Add a comma before each string
        // this adds a comma before the book title
        if (sb.Length > 0) {
             sb.Append(",");
        }
        sb = sb.Clear();
        sb.Append(value);
        wr.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just write directly to the stream instead of building a List?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change your StreamWriter to append:

```
using (var wr = new StreamWriter(filePath, true, Encoding.UTF8))
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f5f5x7kt) for your constructor:

```
public StreamWriter(
    string path,
    bool append,
    Encoding encoding
)
```

appending the file will write to the end of it, instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Your current constructor uses false, which tells the StreamWriter to overwrite the existing file. Setting it to true will tell it to append to the existing file.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As the MSDN docs:

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then
>   closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a
>   file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

So, you can pass the `path` os csv file and the content you want to append and it will do for you without need to manage streams objects. There is two overloads:

[`File.AppendAllText(string path, string contents);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[`File.AppendAllText(string path, string contents, Encoding encoding);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Since you have the `Encoding`, use the second overload, for sample:

```
var rows = new List<string>();

if (userdetails.username != "")
   rows.Add(string.Format("Username: {0}" userdetails.username));
else
   rows.Add("Username: Unknown");

row.Add(string.Empty);

// create the rows you need to append
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string row in rows)
    sb.AppendFormat(",{0}", row);

// flush all rows once time.
File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was so simple. Exactly how i wanted

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `StreamWriter` isn't really correct. You're, only writing one line. You can change  that but changing the instantion to something like;

```
 using (var wr = new StreamWriter(filePath, true, Encoding.UTF8))
```

Or, personally, if you don't risk an OutOfMemoryException (meaning your files are too large to hold in memory) I would just simplify the whole thing with;

```
  List<string> lines = File.ReallAllLines(path);
  lines.Add(String.Join(row, ","));
  File.WriteAllLines(path, lines.ToArray());
```

It's just so much simpler and easier to read.